# Find range of composite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Below I have given my question ,answer and my try (in order) .

> **Exercise:** Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and let $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by $g(x)=4x(1-x),$ $0,\le x\le 1$. If the range of $f\circ g(x)$ is $[\alpha,\beta]$, then $\alpha+\beta$ is equal to:
>
> **Attempt:** $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=f(4x(1-x))=\dfrac{1-4x(1-x)}{1+4x(1-x)}$

But I could not understand how to proceed

Comment: Hint: $f$ is decreasing and $g$ is surjective.

Comment: From the description of the [domain-theory] tag: "Domain theory is a branch of order theory that studies partially ordered sets which are called domains. Do not use this tag for questions about the domain of a function."

Comment: Also, it's about time you develop the ability to use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the range of $f \circ g \subseteq[0,1]$, $g(0)=0, g(1/2)=1$, and $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$.

They are both continuous functions on the given interval. So both $f$ and $g$ take all values in $[0,1]$. In particular $f(g(1/2))=0$ and $f(g(0))=1$ and the composition is continuous , hence the range is $[0,1]$.

**note:** if you are not familiar with continuity etc., then set $y=\frac{1-4x(1-x)}{1+4x(1-x)}$ and solve for a quadratic in $x$ and then proceed from there to find all possible values of $y$.